# Showing the messagebox only once in a loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, messagebox

I have this loop that pops out a message box every time the condition is true.

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim c As Boolean
        c = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        If c = True Then
            cmd3.Connection = con
            con.Open()

            cmd3.CommandText = "insert into student select * from stud where studentno = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "' delete from stud where studentno = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "'"
            dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
            MessageBox.Show("Account approved.")
            con.Close()
        Else

        End If
    Next
```

The messagebox shows as many times as the checked row. And I want to show it just once. I relocate my messagebox everywhere but it does not work. I searched but did not come up for an answer. 
I tried moving it outside the loop but the problem is, the message box still shows even the condition is false.

Thanks!

Comment: Move it outside the loop?  Maybe fire based on a flag that at least one record was added.

Comment: i tried moving it outside the loop, the problem is, the message box shows even the condition is false

Comment: *fire based on a flag that at least one record was added*

Comment: oh ok. i'll search for flags. sorry it's my first time to encounter that. thanks for the info

Comment: `Dim bAdded As Boolean`  (the flag)  then set it (`bAdded = true`)  where you currently have the MsgBox.  Outside the loop: `If bAdded Then...`

Comment: Note that good database design means never having to copy rows from one table to another like that. You are using an entire table to represent some simple data state which could be represented by a boolean column like Active or Registered

Comment: woah i just thought of it a while ago, and because you say so, i'll do it now. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a counter for successful approvals and another counter for unsuccessful approvals and display these after completing the loop. The counters are incremented in the loop depending on the result of the boolean c in each iteration.

```
Dim iSuccessCount As Integer
Dim iFailedCount As Integer

For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim c As Boolean
    c = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value

    If c = True Then
        iSuccessCount +=1
        cmd3.Connection = con
        con.Open()

        cmd3.CommandText = "insert into student select * from stud where studentno = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "' delete from stud where studentno = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "'"
        dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
        con.Close()
    Else
        iFailedCount += 1
    End If
Next

Dim sb As New StringBuilder

sb.Append(iSuccessCount.ToString)
sb.Append(If(iSuccessCount = 1, " account was ", " accounts were "))
sb.Append("approved.")
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
sb.Append(iFailedCount.ToString)
sb.Append(If(iFailedCount = 1, " account was ", " accounts were "))
sb.Append("not approved.")

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
```